If two unitary matrices are similar, does it imply that there exists a unitary intertwiner?
If two unitary matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar, does there exist a unitary intertwining matrix $S$ such that $A = SBS^{-1}$?
My attempts:
I learned that unitary matrices have orthonormal columns and rows, and tried polar decomposition of the intertwiner $S$.

This isn't even true for $1\times 1$ matrices... the question should be if $A$ and $B$ Are similar does it imply that there exists a unitary intertwiner.

@JP McCarthy: Thanks very much for the comment! I will edit the question.

I attempt to answer my question affirmatively:
From MSE: 4595739, the Specht's theorem gives a necessary and sufficient condition for two complex matrices to be unitarily equivalent. For an arbitary word
\begin{align}
W(x,y) = x^{m_1}y^{n_1}x^{m_2}y^{n_2}\dots
\end{align}
with non-negative integer orders, since $A$ is a unitary matrix,
\begin{align}
W(A,A^*) = A^{m-n}\,,
\end{align}
where $m = \sum_{i} m_i$, $n = \sum_{i} n_i$. Similarly,
\begin{align}
W(B,B^*) = B^{m-n}\,.
\end{align}
It follows that $W(A,A^*)$ and $W(B,B^*)$ are similar,
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}( W(A,A^*)) = \text{Tr}( W(B,B^*)) \,,
\end{align}
so $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent.
